# How to add a custom paper size on FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF to create a document. My problem is the paper size requirement is 8.5 by 13 inches. Is there a way to add a custom page size. I tried searching still no avail. When I used **'Legal'** the printing is warped.

```
$pdf = new myPDF('P','in',[8.5,13]);
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'Legal', 0);
$pdf->SetMargins('15', '20', '15');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'PAGE 1', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'Legal', 0);
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'PAGE ', 0, 1, 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm) says, when you create the instance the 3rd parameter may be an array that specifies the width and height. So you may use:

```
$pdf = new myPDF('P','in',[8.5,13]);
```

Comment: how about if I used $pdf->AddPage('P', 'Legal', 0);?